# MySQL like engine: short list of usernames who have liked post design

Tags: mysql

On websites with a Like system (such as Facebook), when you look at a post it will say something such a `You, John, Jane, Smith, and 4 others liked this post` (Facebooks method even limits the names to your friends). I am looking to design a database that will output that info (in my case listing by friends is not necessary).

First table is the `post` table:

```
post_id
user_id
post_text_raw
post_text_sanitized
like_count
```

Second table is the `likes` table:

```
post_id
user_id
```

`user` table for example is:

```
user_id
user_name
salt
password_hash
```

When a post is liked, it iterates the `like_count` cell and inserts a row into the `likes` table.

Two solutions to this have crossed my mind, adding columns to cache the `user_id` into the post table, such as:

```
like_user_id
like_user_id2
like_user_id3
```

And simply using a `JOIN` to match the appropriate username.

The other solution would be to use a sub-query and `LEFT JOIN` to the `likes` table, and another join to the `users` table; however, efficiency in this situation may be of concern.

I am stuck on deciding what the best method to design this is, I've spent the last couple of hours looking for solutions and I have come up empty.

Comment: You already have a very good solution. You simply need to join from `post` to `likes` to `user`

Answer (score 1):

> Two solutions to this have crossed my mind, 
>   1 adding columns to cache
>   the user_id into the post table, such as: `like_user_id like_user_id2 like_user_id3`

No. No. A thousand times no. Don't do this kind of denormalization, or you *will* be sorry.

> The other solution would be to use a sub-query and LEFT JOIN to the
>   likes table, and another join to the users table;

Yes, that's the way to go for an application like this.

> however, efficiency  in this situation may be of concern.

Don't worry about it. SQL is made for this kind of thing. You may need to adjust your indexes when your application scales up. But that is *far* easier than adding columns when you decide a sixth person should be able to  "like" something.

Only when you get to many millions of rows should you consider any kind of denormalization. And by then you will understand your problem space much better than you do now.